# Simple Regex "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$" in batch script not matching six digit number

Tags: regex, batch-file

The problem is in the title. I've created a simple function in windows batch to validate user input. The function exits with "Invalid input" even though i clearly provided a six digit number.

Function:

```
REM Function to Validate Input
:ValidateInput
set error=0
call :Log "Validating input..."
for %%a in (%inputOrders%) do (
    set "order=%%a"
    call :Trim order
    call :Log "Checking order: !order! ..."
    echo !order! | findstr /x "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$" >nul || set "error=1"
    if !error! equ 1 (
        call :Log "Invalid input detected on order !order! Press Y to retry, N to exit."
        echo Invalid input. Press Y to retry, N to exit.
        choice /c YN /n /m "Choose: "
        if errorlevel 2 call :Log "Exiting script due to user choice." && exit /b
    )
)
exit /b
```

Logs:

```
18.01.2024 16:25:18.18 - Main script started. 
18.01.2024 16:26:21.84 - Input received: 661891. 
18.01.2024 16:26:21.84 - Validating input... 
18.01.2024 16:26:21.86 - Checking order: 661891 ... 
18.01.2024 16:26:21.92 - Invalid input detected on order 661891 Press Y to retry, N to exit. 
18.01.2024 16:26:27.09 - Exiting script due to user choice.
```

Note: I use `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`

EDIT:

Here are the missing parts for further context:

inputOrders:

`set /p inputOrders="Enter up to 5 order numbers (6 digits each) separated by commas: "`

Trim:

```
REM Function to trim inputOrders
:Trim
set "var=!%1!"
set "var=%var: =%"
exit /b
```

Final solution:

Removing the space between `!order!` and `|` is the easiest solution to my problem. Thanks a lot for all the different apporaches, i've learned a lot.

`echo !order!| findstr /r "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$" >nul || set "error=1"`

Logs:

```
19.01.2024 12:44:34.76 - Main script started. 
19.01.2024 12:45:25.72 - Input received: 661891,663331,663368,663582,663619 
19.01.2024 12:45:25.73 - Validating input... 
19.01.2024 12:45:25.75 - Checking order: 661891 ... 
19.01.2024 12:45:25.78 - Valid input detected on order 661891. 
19.01.2024 12:45:25.80 - Checking order: 663331 ... 
19.01.2024 12:45:25.84 - Valid input detected on order 663331. 
19.01.2024 12:45:25.84 - Checking order: 663368 ... 
19.01.2024 12:45:25.89 - Valid input detected on order 663368. 
19.01.2024 12:45:25.91 - Checking order: 663582 ... 
19.01.2024 12:45:25.94 - Valid input detected on order 663582. 
19.01.2024 12:45:25.95 - Checking order: 663619 ... 
19.01.2024 12:45:26.00 - Valid input detected on order 663619.
```

Comment: `/x "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$"` does not seem right to me. Either replace `/x` with `/R`, or append `/R` and remove `^` and `$`.

Comment: I should also mention that your regex does not limit the characters to just `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, and `9`. For that you'd need `/R "^[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]$"`. `[0-9]` allows for numeric characters in subscript/superscript too. Also, you should show us exactly how you are getting the input, and passing it to the label.

Comment: Thanks @Compo. I've edited the line combining your input with the answer from @SomethingDark and it works now. `echo !order! | findstr /r "\<[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]\>" >nul || set "error=1"`

Comment: `findstr /r "\<[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]\>"` does not perform the task you laid out. All that is doing is identifying any isolated sequence of six digits. So, an entry of `invalid 185324 input` would still match.

Comment: without even trying - I would expect it to work when the space between `!order!` and `|` gets removed. The space is part of the echoed string, so it ends with a space, not a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findstr` is seeing the newline character that's at the end of the line that gets added when you `echo !order!`, and since `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\r\n` is not the same thing as `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`, you get a failure because you included `^` and `$` in your regex, which says that the pattern should match the entire line. You have a couple of options for getting around this:

## Option 1: write the string without a newline

You can take advantage of the fact that `set /p` will display text to the screen without a trailing newline.

```
<nul set /p "=!order!" | findstr /r "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$" >nul || set "error=1"
```

## Option 2: use the word boundary metacharacters

`findstr /r` uses `\<` and `\>` for the left and right boundaries of a word, respectively.

```
echo !order! | findstr /r "\<[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\>" >nul || set "error=1"
```

Note that for both of these options, I'm using the `/r` flag instead of the `/x` flag to tell the command that this is a regular expression; `/x` means "Prints lines that match exactly."

Comment: As an possible alternative, ```(Set order) 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IR "order=[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]$" 1>NUL || (Call :Log...```.

Answer (score 1):

I have to disagree with a number of statements made here.

Unfortunately, there is no information about the contents of `inputorders`. It's not a file, since the `for` is not a `for /f` so it appears it's a list of elements with standard separators.

I tested with

```
SET "inputorders=U:\ 123 1x22 "hello" "123456" 1-2345 661891 42"
```

There's no indication of what `:trim` does, so I chose to have it merely dequote `order`. Given the code provided, `%%a` and hence `order` would never have leading or trailing spaces.

Similarly, I had `:log` append `%*` to a file.

Next,

```
set error=0
```

needs to be moved inside the loop, otherwise once it is set to `1`, it will remain set to `1`. Sure - that means there is an error in the set of values provided, but the error-reporting will report an error on every value after the first error; erroneous or not.

Finally, `Stephan`'s point about the trailing space is absolutely valid. The key to getting `findstr` to recognise the validity of the value is to remove that space.

Once the space is removed,

```
findstr /x "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$"
findstr    "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$"
findstr /x "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

all work as expected.

Comment: In this case, it's not a problem. As soon as an invalid input is detected, it'll ask to re-enter or quit the script completely. But you're certainly right and i've moved it inside the subroutine.